# Error when uploading my database from SQL server 2017 to Azure SQL server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure-sql-database

When I use SQL server 2017 database tool to upload my database, I got this error.

[image]

When I generate .bacpac file by myself and upload to azure storage account, then import to azure sql server, I also get the same error.

This database is generated from my asp core project using Entity framework, I generate to sql server 2017 to add more performance update like: partition table, indexing table. After that, I upload this database to Azure cloud, then I get this error.

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to remove the login Admin at the database level before trying to migrate to Azure SQL Database again. Admin is not a valid login name you can use in Azure SQL Database.

I usually recommend users to use [Azure Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) (DMA) to migrate a SQL Server database to Azure SQL Database, because it performs an assessment first and let you know things you need to fix prior to migrate to Azure SQL. Once all incompatibilities are fixed, DMA allows you to migrate with a couple of clicks.

Comment: work like a charm! thank you, but azure sql database not support Sql server 's table partition. @Alberto Morillo

Comment: Table partitioning is available on Azure SQL Database. Just take a look at this article: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3494/azure-sql-database--table-partitioning/